# Word for "fixing attention"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I remember there's a word that means people/animal fixing their attention on something. It could be used to describe wolves or otherwise circling around preys. Does anyone know what that word might be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another way of saying "to pay close attention to"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156336/another-way-of-saying-to-pay-close-attention-to)

Comment: maybe to ***fixate*** on something.

Comment: *focus* on something

Answer (score 2):

Hard to know exactly what you're looking for ... so I'll focus on predators circling prey.

How about ***stalk***?

Dictionary.com:

> [***stalk***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stalk?s=t): to pursue or
>   approach prey, quarry, etc., stealthily

Your example:

> The ravenous gray wolves ***stalked*** the young injured doe.

Answer (score 1):

Rapt maybe, I was taught it meant very focused but now that I look it up it says it means someone's fascinated or captivated in whatever's happening.